# What's the default order of Linux sort?

Tags: linux, sort, locale

For a long period I thought the default behavior of the `sort` program was using ASCII order. However, when I input the following lines into `sort` without any arguments:

```
#
@
```

I got:

```
@
#
```

But according to the ASCII table, `#` is 35 and `@` is 64. Another example is:

```
A
a
```

And the output is:

```
a
A
```

Can anybody explain this? By the way, what is 'dictionary-order' when using `sort -d`?

Comment: sort order depends on your locale settings

Comment: But it is alphabetical order by default at least in GNU sort.

Comment: Nobody answered the question what the default sort order is. Man page does not mention "alphabetical order", only dictionary-order. However, no mention if that is the default, and no description what that precisely is.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Looks like you are using a non-POSIX locale.

Try:

```
export LC_ALL=C
```

and then `sort`.

`info sort` clearly says:

> (1) If you use a non-POSIX locale (e.g., by setting `LC_ALL' to
>   `en_US'), then `sort' may produce output that is sorted differently
>   than you're accustomed to.  In that case, set the `LC_ALL' environment
>   variable to `C'. Note that setting only `LC_COLLATE' has two problems.
>   First, it is ineffective if `LC_ALL' is also set.  Second, it has
>   undefined behavior if `LC_CTYPE' (or `LANG', if `LC_CTYPE' is unset) is
>   set to an incompatible value.  For example, you get undefined behavior
>   if `LC_CTYPE' is `ja_JP.PCK' but `LC_COLLATE' is `en_US.UTF-8'.

Comment: The OP is asking what the sort order is, not how to change it.

Comment: Thanks, I've tested on my machine and locale settings do affect sort behavior

Answer (score 5):

As `man sort` says, “dictionary-order” means
“consider only blanks and alphanumeric characters”. 
For example, given the data

```
The
!quick
brown
@fox
jumps
#over
17
$lazy
  dogs
%42
times.
```

the unadorned `sort` command produces

```
  dogs
!quick
#over
$lazy
%42
@fox
17
brown
jumps
The
times.
```

(putting the lines that begin with the space characters
and the `!`, `#`, `$`, `%`, and `@` symbols<sup>1</sup>
ahead of the lines that begin with letters and numbers;
i.e., ***alphanumeric characters***), but `sort -d` produces

```
  dogs
17
%42
brown
@fox
jumps
$lazy
#over
!quick
The
times.
```

`dogs` is still first, because it begins with spaces,
but the special (punctuation) characters are ignored. 
`17` comes before `42`, and `fox` comes between `brown` and `jumps`,
in spite of the fact that `42` and `fox` have characters in front of them
that would normally move them before the `17`.
____________
<sup>1</sup> in order of their ASCII values:
space=040, `!`=041, `#`=043, `$`=044, `%`=045, and `@`=0100. 
Note that (disregarding the space bar)
this is approximately left-to-right order on some keyboards.

Comment: The order in your first example, where text is sorted first on punctuation, may result if the locale in effect is C (as with LC_ALL=C) but not in other locales. Which locale is the **default** depends on the OS settings. So, an *unadorned* `sort` should be different in many Distributions.

Answer (score 3):

To determine the sort order, simply create a file with a different character on each line and the sort it. The resulting output will tell you the sort order.

Comment: Nice, simple and efficient

Comment: Generally a very good idea, but it is not always enough. A collation need not be defined only on individual characters. Some collations treat "ae" as if it were a ligature, or treat ligatures as if they were decomposed. Another case is that many collations treat 'a' and 'A' as equal, but the order you see by testing doesn't tell you that (it may tell you whether the sort is stable). And a single-character test doesn't tell if tab expansion, whitespace normalization, etc. are in effect. Nevertheless, it's a very good place to start.

Comment: (too late to edit previous comment) -- so long as you actually include a diverse enough range of characters, you can tell case-ignoring from seeing (for example) aAbB instead of abAB.