# Does comma come before numbers when sorting?

Tags: sort

I have a file `foo` whose contents are

```
140,22
236,224
2,86
```

If I sort it with `sort foo` I get the same result. This tells me that `,` comes after numbers, or at the very least that `,` comes after `3`.

Paradoxically, the following happens:

```
$echo -e "2\n,\n3" | sort
,
2
3
```

Which tells me that `,` comes before `2`. I don't get it. Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sort order [depends on your locale](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/43465/18887), so there's probably some odd interpretation going on there. I get the same results as you on my system. Here, a comma is *ignored* by the locale. Hence, if we add `276` and `296` to your list:

```
$ sort /tmp/tosort
140,22
236,224
276
2,86
296
```

This also explains the results from your second command. The comma isn't being sorted *first*, but being ignored. Hence, it's essentially sorting a empty string. If you add a literal empty string to your test, you'll also see it at the beginning.

```
$ echo -e "2\n,\n3\n" | sort

,
2
3
```

(It's unclear to me why the empty string precedes the comma. I suspect that the comma is used when there is a tie.)

You will get more predictable results using a "standard" POSIX locale.

```
$ export LC_ALL=C
$ sort foo
140,22
2,86
236,224
```

Comment: I want to sort lexicographically. The two bottom rows tie on the first character and the second one compares `3` to `,` and places `3` before the comma.

Comment: I don't get how locale can account for inconsistencies in sorting with the same locale.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, Sparhawk. The example doesn't help me. `echo -e "9\n," | sort` does place the comma before `9`, which very odd, but at least it is consistent. I still don't get why it behaves the way it does. It's the same locale for both sorts.

Comment: @Can'tSortThis No worries. Edited again

Comment: Got it! Thanks.